# Is it possible to pass a flag to Gulp to have it run tasks in different ways?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

Normally in Gulp tasks look like this:

```
gulp.task('my-task', function() {
    return gulp.src(options.SCSS_SOURCE)
        .pipe(sass({style:'nested'}))
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 10 version'))
        .pipe(concat('style.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(options.SCSS_DEST));
});
```

Is it possible to pass a command line flag to gulp (that's not a task) and have it run tasks conditionally based on that? For instance

```
$ gulp my-task -a 1
```

And then in my gulpfile.js:

```
gulp.task('my-task', function() {
        if (a == 1) {
            var source = options.SCSS_SOURCE;
        } else {
            var source = options.OTHER_SOURCE;
        }
        return gulp.src(source)
            .pipe(sass({style:'nested'}))
            .pipe(autoprefixer('last 10 version'))
            .pipe(concat('style.css'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(options.SCSS_DEST));
});
```

Comment: As it's running in node, you could probably use `process.argv` to access the command line arguments.

Answer (score 531, accepted):

Gulp doesn't offer any kind of util for that, but you can use one of the many command args parsers. I like [`yargs`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/yargs). Should be:

```js
var argv = require('yargs').argv;

gulp.task('my-task', function() {
    return gulp.src(argv.a == 1 ? options.SCSS_SOURCE : options.OTHER_SOURCE)
        .pipe(sass({style:'nested'}))
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 10 version'))
        .pipe(concat('style.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(options.SCSS_DEST));
});
```

You can also combine it with [`gulp-if`](https://github.com/robrich/gulp-if) to conditionally pipe the stream, very useful for dev vs. prod building:

```
var argv = require('yargs').argv,
    gulpif = require('gulp-if'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('my-js-task', function() {
  gulp.src('src/**/*.js')
    .pipe(concat('out.js'))
    .pipe(gulpif(argv.production, uglify()))
    .pipe(gulpif(argv.production, rename({suffix: '.min'})))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});
```

And call with `gulp my-js-task` or `gulp my-js-task --production`.

Comment: This should be somehow mentioned @ the official gulp github, essential stuff!

Comment: This, video explains how to achieve this without yargs: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gRzCAyNrPV8

Comment: Hi @plankguy, the video is very nice. Thanks. It shows how to parse the environment variables by hand, without any lib. A small difference is that the video is about *environment variables*, while the example above is about *command line arguments*, where Yargs is yet another tool that helps simplify the consumption by abstracting the variables parsing.

Comment: Incase anyone else is looking for how to do multiple conditions with gulp-if ------->          `.pipe($.if(argv.prod, $.if('*.js', $.uglify()) ))` (where the $.if = gulpif)

Comment: If you use `npm run gulp` then you should use it like `npm run gulp -- --production`.

Comment: This is mentioned @ the [official gulp github](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/CLI.md#task-specific-flags) (literally).

Comment: You cannot use `gulpif(argv.production, ...` but instead you should use `gulpif(!!argv.production,...` to convert expected condition to boolean.

Answer (score 105):

**Edit**

`gulp-util` is [deprecated](https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5) and should be avoid, so it's recommended to use [minimist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minimist) instead, which `gulp-util` already used.

So I've changed some lines in my gulpfile to remove `gulp-util`:

```
var argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));

gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return gulp.src(['src/styles/' + (argv.theme || 'main') + '.scss'])
    …
});
```

**Original**

In my project I use the following flag:

```
gulp styles --theme literature
```

Gulp offers an object `gulp.env` for that. It's deprecated in newer versions, so you must use gulp-util for that. The tasks looks like this:

```
var util = require('gulp-util');

gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return gulp.src(['src/styles/' + (util.env.theme ? util.env.theme : 'main') + '.scss'])
    .pipe(compass({
        config_file: './config.rb',
        sass   : 'src/styles',
        css    : 'dist/styles',
        style  : 'expanded'

    }))
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'ff 17', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'))
    .pipe(livereload(server))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/styles'))
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'Styles task complete' }));
});
```

The environment setting is available during all subtasks. So I can use this flag on the watch task too:

```
gulp watch --theme literature
```

And my styles task also works.

Ciao
Ralf

Comment: [`gulp.env` is being deprecated](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#35), as you can see by the console log message when running it. They ask you to use your own parser and suggest `yargs` or `minimist`.

Comment: Thanks @CaioToOn for your hint. I've updated my answer and my project too ;)

Comment: You can shorten `util.env.theme ? util.env.theme : 'main'` to `util.env.theme || 'main'`. Anyway +1.

Comment: `gulp-util` utilizes `minimist` library for command line argument parsing. So if you're using `gulp-util`, you don't need an extra library for that purpose. Document: https://github.com/substack/minimist

Answer (score 58):

Here's a quick recipe I found:

### gulpfile.js

```
var gulp   = require('gulp');

// npm install gulp yargs gulp-if gulp-uglify
var args   = require('yargs').argv;
var gulpif = require('gulp-if');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

var isProduction = args.env === 'production';

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src('**/*.js')
    .pipe(gulpif(isProduction, uglify())) // only minify if production
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

### CLI

```
gulp scripts --env production
```

Original Ref (not available anymore): https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/pass-params-from-cli.md

## Alternative with minimist

From Updated Ref: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/pass-arguments-from-cli.md

### gulpfile.js

```
// npm install --save-dev gulp gulp-if gulp-uglify minimist

var gulp = require('gulp');
var gulpif = require('gulp-if');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

var minimist = require('minimist');

var knownOptions = {
  string: 'env',
  default: { env: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production' }
};

var options = minimist(process.argv.slice(2), knownOptions);

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src('**/*.js')
    .pipe(gulpif(options.env === 'production', uglify())) // only minify if production
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

### CLI

```
gulp scripts --env production
```

Comment: That recipe link seems gone now. There is another one that uses the minimist package instead: [pass-arguments-from-cli.md](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/pass-arguments-from-cli.md). That makes sense since gulp itself [uses minimist](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/package.json#L27).

Answer (score 40):

There's a very simple way to do `on/off` flags without parsing the arguments. `gulpfile.js` is just a file that's executed like any other, so you can do:

```
var flags = {
  production: false
};

gulp.task('production', function () {
  flags.production = true;
});
```

And use something like `gulp-if` to conditionally execute a step

```
gulp.task('build', function () {
  gulp.src('*.html')
    .pipe(gulp_if(flags.production, minify_html()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'));
});
```

Executing `gulp build` will produce a nice html, while `gulp production build` will minify it.

Comment: Great idea, saves using yargs,  I've extended this by having a 'pre-production' task that sets the vars and then 'production' has a dependency array of ['build','pre-production'].  That way you can just run 'gulp production'.

Comment: Nice! I'm using this before setting the stream, with `gulp.task('mytask', function() { if (flags.myflag ) { flaggedtask } else { unflaggedask } });`

Comment: I think this is the gulp way to do it

Comment: @Keegan'shairstyle82 I did something similar but had to utilize [run-sequence](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence) to ensure there were no race conditions when setting properties of `flags`.

Comment: The disadvantage of this method is that you have to change gulpfile.js every time you want to change flag variables, rather than just passing arguments to the gulp command in the terminal.

Comment: Be warned that `gulp production build` will run tasks `production` and `build` in *parallel* by default, so this technique might be vulnerable to a race condition, however unlikely. Use `gulp production build --series` to clear the risk.

Answer (score 36):

If you've some strict (ordered!) arguments, then you can get them simply by checking `process.argv`.

```
var args = process.argv.slice(2);

if (args[0] === "--env" && args[1] === "production");
```

Execute it: `gulp --env production`

...however, I think that this is *tooo* strict and not bulletproof! So, I fiddled a bit around... and ended up with this utility function:

```
function getArg(key) {
  var index = process.argv.indexOf(key);
  var next = process.argv[index + 1];
  return (index < 0) ? null : (!next || next[0] === "-") ? true : next;
}
```

It eats an argument-name and will search for this in `process.argv`. If nothing was found it spits out `null`. Otherwise if their is no next argument or the next argument is a command and not a value (we differ with a dash) `true` gets returned. (That's because the key exist, but there's just no value). If all the cases before will fail, the next argument-value is what we get.

**`> gulp watch --foo --bar 1337 -boom "Foo isn't equal to bar."`**

```
getArg("--foo") // => true
getArg("--bar") // => "1337"
getArg("-boom") // => "Foo isn't equal to bar."
getArg("--404") // => null
```

Ok, enough for now... Here's a simple example using *gulp*:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var sass = require("gulp-sass");
var rename = require("gulp-rename");

var env = getArg("--env");

gulp.task("styles", function () {
  return gulp.src("./index.scss")
  .pipe(sass({
    style: env === "production" ? "compressed" : "nested"
  }))
  .pipe(rename({
    extname: env === "production" ? ".min.css" : ".css"
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest("./build"));
});
```

Run it `gulp --env production`

Comment: argument name should be prefixed with dash(es): `if (args[0] === '--env' && args[1] === 'production');`, at least in gulp 3.8.11

Comment: @yckart - you should probably add the require('..') for getArg in your code example.

Answer (score 7):

I built a plugin to inject parameters from the commandline into the task callback.

```
gulp.task('mytask', function (production) {
  console.log(production); // => true
});

// gulp mytask --production
```

https://github.com/stoeffel/gulp-param

If someone finds a bug or has a improvement to it, I am happy to merge PRs.

Answer (score 4):

And if you are using typescript (`gulpfile.ts`) then do this for `yargs` (building on @Caio Cunha's excellent answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/23038290/1019307 and other comments above):

### Install

```
npm install --save-dev yargs

typings install dt~yargs --global --save
```

#### `.ts` files

Add this to the .ts files:

```
import { argv } from 'yargs';

...

  let debug: boolean = argv.debug;
```

This has to be done in each .ts file individually (even the `tools/tasks/project` files that are imported into the `gulpfile.ts/js`).

### Run

```
gulp build.dev --debug
```

Or under `npm` pass the arg through to gulp:

```
npm run build.dev -- --debug
```

Answer (score 2):

### Pass arguments from the command line

```
// npm install --save-dev gulp gulp-if gulp-uglify minimist

var gulp = require('gulp');
var gulpif = require('gulp-if');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

var minimist = require('minimist');

var knownOptions = {
  string: 'env',
  default: { env: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production' }
};

var options = minimist(process.argv.slice(2), knownOptions);

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src('**/*.js')
    .pipe(gulpif(options.env === 'production', uglify())) // only minify in production
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Then run gulp with:

```
$ gulp scripts --env development
```

[Source](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/edit/master/docs/recipes/pass-arguments-from-cli.md)

Answer (score 2):

```
var isProduction = (process.argv.indexOf("production")>-1);
```

CLI `gulp production` calls my production task and sets a flag for any conditionals.

Answer (score 1):

We wanted to pass a different config file for different environments -- one for **production**, **dev** and **testing**. This is the code in the gulp file:

```js
//passing in flag to gulp to set environment
//var env = gutil.env.env;

if (typeof gutil.env.env === 'string') {
  process.env.NODE_ENV = gutil.env.env;
}
```

This is the code in the app.js file:

```js
  if(env === 'testing'){
      var Config = require('./config.testing.js');
      var Api = require('./api/testing.js')(Config.web);
    }
    else if(env === 'dev'){
       Config = require('./config.dev.js');
        Api = require('./api/dev.js').Api;
    }
    else{
       Config = require('./config.production.js');
       Api = require('./api/production.js')(Config.web);
    }
```

And then to run it gulp `--env=testing`

Answer (score 1):

It has been some time since this question has been posted, but maybe it will help someone.

I am using GULP CLI 2.0.1 (installed globally) and GULP 4.0.0 (installed locally) here is how you do it without any additional plugin. I think the code is quite self-explanatory.

```
var cp = require('child_process'), 
{ src, dest, series, parallel, watch } = require('gulp');

// == availableTasks: log available tasks to console
function availableTasks(done) {
  var command = 'gulp --tasks-simple';
  if (process.argv.indexOf('--verbose') > -1) {
    command = 'gulp --tasks';
  }
  cp.exec(command, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    done(console.log('Available tasks are:\n' + stdout));
  });
}
availableTasks.displayName = 'tasks';
availableTasks.description = 'Log available tasks to console as plain text list.';
availableTasks.flags = {
  '--verbose': 'Display tasks dependency tree instead of plain text list.'
};
exports.availableTasks = availableTasks;
```

And run from the console:

```
gulp availableTasks
```

Then run and see the differences:

```
gulp availableTasks --verbose
```