# How can I pass argument with parameter to gulp?

Tags: angularjs, gulp

I want to do something like

```
gulp build --param1=abc
```

and I want this param to be available in Angular Service/Controller.
Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: what do u mean in ur angular service/controller?

Comment: @YangLi I want to be able to use the value 'abc' in an AngularJS service.
for now I have piped the value in file and importing that file with $http in my service. I am not sure if there is a better approach.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to pass a flag to Gulp to have it run tasks in different ways?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23023650/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-flag-to-gulp-to-have-it-run-tasks-in-different-ways)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. I would recommend in your Gulp config, you create an Angular constant that can be injected into any part of the application.

```
var ngConstant = require('gulp-ng-constant');
var args = require('yargs').argv;

gulp.task('constant', function () {
  var selectedConstant = args.env || 'dev'; // if --env is not declared, assume dev
  var constants = {
    dev: {
      ENV: {
        'api': 'api.someUrl.com',
        'url': 'dev.url.com'
      }
    },
    prod: {
      ENV: {
        'api': 'api.someUrl.com',
        'url': 'dev.url.com'
      }
    },
  };

  return ngConstant({
      name: 'app', // name of your module
      constants: constants[selectedConstant],
      stream: true
    })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src'));
});

gulp.task('build', function () {
  runSequence(
    ['constant']
  )
});
```

Now, you can run `gulp build --env=prod` and that will create a file called `constants.js` in your `/src/` folder (or wherever you specify). Now include this file in your `index.html`.

You can now inject the constant `ENV` anywhere in your services or controllers and reference the variables within.

```
angular.module('app')

.service('SomeService', function(ENV) {
  // access ENV vars here
});

.controller('SomeCtrl', function($scope, ENV) {
  // access ENV vars here
});
```

Comment: @ap_snitch : does this answer your question?