# How to use yargs array syntax with gulp?

Tags: arrays, gulp, yargs

Using array syntax of yargs with gulp throws errors. Here is my code:

```
var argv = require("yargs")
  .array("modules")
  .argv;
```

and using it like this:

```
gulp taskname --modules m1 m2
Task 'm2' is not in your gulpfile
```

How can I set an array using yargs in gulp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround for it:

```
gulp taskname --modules m1 --modules m2
```

Answer (score 0):

**Watch out!** 
If you wan't to use required parameter via Gulp. In this case, yargs dosn't act like expected.

See here for more Information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41412558/1256697