# gulp - variable argument in task

Tags: gulp

I've checked already some other answers here on stack overflow ([23023650](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23023650/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-flag-to-gulp-to-have-it-run-tasks-in-different-ways), [28538918](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538918/pass-parameter-to-gulp-task)), but they all seam to cover something that is slightly different from what I'm after.

Basically, what i'd like to do is something like this:

```
gulp compileUnit -about
```

where `about` is my page name.

The goal here for me is to be able to use different pages, and change the path according to the page.

Little example:

```
var argv = require('yargs');
var gulpif = require('gulp-if');

var singleUnit = argv; //hoping that singleUnit = about

var paths: {compile: [singleUnit],...}
gulp.task('compileUnit', function (done) {
    gulp.src(paths.compile)
        .pipe(coffee({bare: true})
            .on('error', gutil.log.bind(gutil, 'Coffee Error')))
        .pipe(concat('unit.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/tests/unit/'))
        .on('end', done)
});
```

The code above should be pretty easy, but I'll explain a bit more in detail:

I'd like to set `singleUnit` value to be the param I typed in (`gulp compileUnit -about`) so that the path to run `gulp compileUnit` changes to about.

I hope this is clear enough.
Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already use `gulp-util`. What's about with a similar solution like https://stackoverflow.com/a/23088183/1295622?

```
var singleUnit = gutil.env.page; //hoping that singleUnit = about

var paths: {compile: [singleUnit],...}

gulp.task('compileUnit', function (done) {
    gulp.src(paths.compile)
        .pipe(coffee({bare: true})
            .on('error', gutil.log.bind(gutil, 'Coffee Error')))
        .pipe(concat('unit.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/tests/unit/'))
        .on('end', done)
});
```

And then

```
gulp compileUnit --page about
```