# Passing a string as a parameter to a gulp task

Tags: javascript, gulp

```
  var gulp = require("grunt");

    gulp.task('taskName', function(strng) {
        console.log(strng);
    });
```

Generally, the gulp file is run as "gulp taskName"
I want to know how to pass "strng" with the taskName in command line as a parameter

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23023650/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-flag-to-gulp-to-have-it-run-tasks-in-different-ways

Comment: cant we use something like gulp taskName:strng as in grunt

Comment: as i recall "gulp taskName:strng" its not an argument its calling subtask "strng"

Comment: without using yargs, cant we do it? How we will pass asrgument to the function taskName?

Comment: How about something like " gulp gulptask --strng value" ?

Comment: yea, even I was thinking of the same. Let me be brief about my use case. I have a string which i need to manipulate as a valid string using a function with Gulp. I have a function, say, "function(string) { }". Using gulp gulptask --strng value...... How will I find out which is my string and value. Is is something like "--options 3". If so how may I proceed with such a use case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass Parameter to Gulp Task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538918/pass-parameter-to-gulp-task)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may consider using `yargs`

reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs

In your gulpfile
`var args = require('yargs').argv;`

In your command line
`$ gulp taskName --yourparamvariable=bar`

To access the paramerter you've sent from your command line
`args.yourparamvariable`

Comment: I've used this technique in some of my gulp tasks and it works really well.