# Selective app compilation

Tags: nativescript

I'm developing an app and there'll be a few variations. Same app - different icons, some app pages and logic - about 95% same.

Is it possible to include just the necessary files at build time?

Answer (score 0):

For this I would probably use gulp/grunt and have some custom build time logic. This would ensure minimum redundancy in the final app.

So you might use [`gulp-copy`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-copy) and then have a build_config_1 job which includes:

```
return gulp.src(sourceFiles)
  .pipe($.copy(outputPath, options));
```

where `var sourceFiles = commonFiles + thisConfig` and `thisConfig` is specific for this configuration.

You could alternatively have 1 build task and then specify the configuration as a command argument - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538918/pass-parameter-to-gulp-task).