# How can I add support for .NET web application virtual paths in gulp?

Tags: .net, gulp, less

I am using gulp with a .NET Core web application and I have a Less file that contains paths to physical files like so:

```
background: @colour-background-darkest-base url(/content/slides/experience.jpg) no-repeat center top fixed;
```

But when I run the web application in a virtual path the image can't be found. How can I provide support for virtual paths so that I can do the following:

```
background: @colour-background-darkest-base url(~/content/slides/experience.jpg) no-repeat center top fixed;
```

(Note the ~ at the start of the path)

Comment: are you having your LESS files compiled in-browser using less.js?

Comment: No, gulp is compiling Less via the `ProjectOpened` binding in Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Not the best idea, but you could pass variables into the LESS options in gulpfile.js (`globalVars`), however you would need to get the base url into gulp instead. Maybe this could do that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538918/pass-parameter-to-gulp-task

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 constructs the commands so I have no control over them as far as I'm aware, I might consider raising this with MS to see what they propose. This isn't a problem on the command line as the solution you mentioned will work but I was hoping for something that would work on development machines and build machines.

Comment: They are different questions, both asked by myself, even though the solution is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been answered in the following SO question:
[Use Bower package version numbers in Razor views for CDN support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46713286/use-bower-package-version-numbers-in-razor-views-for-cdn-support)

In a nutshell, combine gulp with [Bundling and Minification with ASP.Net MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification#using-bundling-and-minification-with-aspnet-mvc)