# Use Bower package version numbers in Razor views for CDN support

Tags: razor, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, bower

I am using Bower in Visual Studio 2017 to install packages such as Bootstrap and jQuery.

In my views I am referencing the same libraries using a CDN like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css"
          asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
          asp-fallback-test-class="glyphicon"
          asp-fallback-test-property="visibility"
          asp-fallback-test-value="hidden" />
```

If I change the version of Bootstrap in Bower from 3.3.7 to something else, I then have to remember to go into the Razor view and change **3.3.7** to the updated version number.

Should I use Gulp to read the bower.json file and automatically generate a Razor view with the correct Boostrap version number or is there an easier way to ensure Bower and my Razor files are kept in sync?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better create a bundle with all your javascript. 
[Bundling and Minification with ASP.Net MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification#using-bundling-and-minification-with-aspnet-mvc)

When you bower update, during runtime, bundling will automatically change the JS bundle so that your client will get the latest version.

Comment: That is a really good idea, can't believe I didn't think of that, for some reason I was thinking you should use either one or the other but combining the two makes perfect sense. Thanks!