# Pass data between gulp 4 tasks, pipes or commandline

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp, gulp-4

I'm trying to do in my opinion a simple task but can't figure it out. Can't find it on google or here. Maybe i'm doing it completely wrong.

I need to change a property in a json file with gulp 4. To get the new value of the property I have another task or pipe (I don't care :-)) and want to pass it along.

Also, how to pass variable from command line? so in example: `gulp release -branchname "foobar"`

How can I do this. I know there are similar question here but nothing is working for me...

```js
    var gulp = require('gulp');
var git = require('gulp-git');
var jeditor = require("gulp-json-editor");

var paths = {
    manifest: "vss-extension.json"
}

function getBranchName(){
    console.log("Get the current branch name");

    return git.revParse({args:'--abbrev-ref HEAD'}, function (err, branch) {
        console.log('current git branch: ' + branch);
        var currentBranch = branch;

        return currentBranch;
    });

    // console.log("Current branch is: "+ branchName);

    // return branchName;
}

function updateExtensionManifestVersion(foo){

    var x = 10;

    gulp.src(paths.manifest)
    .pipe(jeditor(function(json) {
        console.log("Append current branchname " + currentBranch + " to extension manifest id");

        var currentId = json.id;
        console.log("Current manifest id: "+ currentId);

        // var branchName = git.revParse({args:'--abbrev-ref HEAD'}, function (err, branch) {
        //     console.log('current git branch: ' + branch);
        //     return branch;
        // });

        // console.log(branchName.branch);

        var newId = currentId + "-" + branchName;
        console.log("New manifest id: " + newId);
        json.id = newId;

        return json;
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.manifest));
}

gulp.task('release', gulp.series(getBranchName, updateExtensionManifestVersion, function(done) {
    console.log("release is done");
    done();
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass variables from command line you can use [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs) as explained in this answer [Pass Parameter to Gulp Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538918/pass-parameter-to-gulp-task).

If you want to pass data between tasks set a global variable that will be accessible to both.