# Gulp run task as per key in array of object

Tags: javascript, gulp

For copying files to destination I am using simple gulp's src and dest

I want to specify this copy action as per key in obj:

```
    var copy = {
            first: {
                dest: 'dist/index.scala.html',
                src: 'app/index.scala.html'
            },
            second: {
                dest: 'dist/setup.scala.html',
                src: 'app/setup.scala.html'
            }
      };
```

I am able to create copy task and copy files as per src and dest mentioned in object But I need something like:

```
    gulp copy:first //this will only copy from src to dest as specifided under 'first' key

    gulp copy:second //this will only copy from src to dest as specifided under 'second' key
```

Like how we achieve in grunt.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/pass-parameters-gulp-tasks/) "it’s not possible to pass arguments on the command line which can be used by that task".

That said, you can do something like this:

```
const gulp = require("gulp");

const copy = {
    first: {
        dest: 'dist/index.scala.html',
        src: 'app/index.scala.html'
    },
    second: {
        dest: 'dist/setup.scala.html',
        src: 'app/setup.scala.html'
    }
};

for (let key in copy) {
    gulp.task('copy:' + key, cb => {
        console.log('copy[key]: ', copy[key]);
        cb();
    });
}
```

Note: I've changed `copy = [`...`]` to `copy = {`...`}` because arrays can't have strings (such as 'first') as keys but objects can.

Then to run the gulp commands:

`gulp copy:first`

`gulp copy:second`

You may also want to have a look at [Pass Parameter to Gulp Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538918/pass-parameter-to-gulp-task).