# How to make a gulp task with param?

Tags: gulp

There is a gulp task:

```
gulp.task('copy-bower-components-to-dev', function () {
  gulp.src('./app/bower_components/**')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dev/bower_components'));
});
```

I also need the same task for another folder:

```
gulp.task('copy-bower-components-to-prod', function () {
  gulp.src('./app/bower_components/**')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('prod/bower_components'));
});
```

But it is not a clean code; how can I make a gulp task with params(in this case param with a folder name)? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can send it an argument -dev or -prod http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23023650/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-flag-to-gulp-to-have-it-run-tasks-in-different-ways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `gulp-utils` are actually perfect for this:

```
var gutil = require('gulp-util');

function destination() {
    return (!!gutil.env.type && gutil.env.type == 'prod' ? 'prod' : 'dev';
}

gulp.task('copy-bower-components', function () {
  return gulp.src('./app/bower_components/**')
    .pipe(gulp.dest(destination() + '/bower_components'));
});
```

Run it with `gulp --type=prod` to set the new folder!

Comment: Thanks! It works! Also, may I set some flags for task by default? For example, for this task: gulp.task('build-dev', ['translate-sass', 'translate-coffee', 'translate-slim', 'copy-bower-components', 'connect'])

Comment: I updated the answer to make it more failsafe: The default value for destination is `'dev'` in that example -- that should work for your other flags as well ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this plugin [gulp-foal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-foal) to run a foal-task with param.

**param NOT from cmd.**

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var clean = require('gulp-clean');
var foal = require('gulp-foal');

//use "foal.task(...)" to define a foal-task.
foal.task('clean_some', function(cleanPath) {
  //"return" shall not be missed for running foal-task orderly.
  return gulp.src(cleanPath)
    .pipe(clean());
});

gulp.task('default', function(cb) {
  //use "foal.run(...)" to run your foal-task with param.
  foal.run(clean_some('test_path'), cb);
});
```