# Execute gulp task only if flag is passed?

Tags: gulp

Current Code:

```
var open = require('open');
var gulp = require("gulp");
var pkg = require("../../package.json");

//opens the launchpage with default browser
gulp.task("open", function () {
    open('http://localhost:' + pkg.webServerPort + '/commonclient/launchpage.html');
});
```

Right now, running the `gulp` command starts the server and does a bunch of other compilation tasks. How to modify this to run the "open" task only if I type in `gulp -o` or something like that in command line?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to pass a flag to Gulp to have it run tasks in different ways?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23023650/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-flag-to-gulp-to-have-it-run-tasks-in-different-ways)

Comment: Sometimes I think that 90% of the comments on StackOverflow these days are "possible duplicate of" responses. I'm starting to think it's a bot. Nostalgic about the days when people actually answered the questions to help fellow developers.

Comment: Sometimes removing duplication _is_ an actual aid to other developers. This question (albeit not in this exact form) has already been answered much better than I could answer it in the suggested duplicate.

Comment: We are answering it, by telling giving you the link to the solution. Why spend the energy to write the exact same answer? If the linked solution doesn't work for you, then explain why.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by inspecting [`process.argv`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html), or simply looking for an ENV flag on `process.env`

```
gulp.task("open", function () {
  if (process.argv.indexOf('-o') > -1) {
    open('http://localhost:' + pkg.webServerPort + '/commonclient/launchpage.html');
  }
});
```

Or with an env variable

```
gulp.task("open", function () {
  if (processs.env.USE_OPEN) {
    open('http://localhost:' + pkg.webServerPort + '/commonclient/launchpage.html');
  }
});
```