# Get project platform and configuration in Gulp or Grunt

Tags: asp.net, .net, gruntjs, gulp

I wonder if I could get the `ASP.NET` project configuration and platform in `gulpfile.js` or `gruntfile.js`? I mean e.g. `Debug|AnyCPU` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, but for obvious reasons you only can if you call gulp from a tool that knows those details, e.g. msbuild.

Suppose you've just created a fresh, Empty ASP.NET Web Application for .NET 4.5.2 using Visual Studio 2015, you can add something like this to the `Build` or `AfterBuild` `Target`:

```xml
<exec command='gulp --env="$(Configuration)|$(Platform)"' />
```

You then need to [parse arguments in gulp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23023650/419956), e.g. using `yargs`:

```javascript
require('gulp').task("default", function() {
  console.log(require('yargs').argv.env);
});
```

This will write something like this if you build in Visual Studio:

> ```
>   1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: GulpFromMsbuild, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
>   1>  GulpFromMsbuild -> D:\GulpFromMsbuild\bin\GulpFromMsbuild.dll
>   1>  [20:07:41] Using gulpfile D:\GulpFromMsbuild\gulpfile.js
>   1>  [20:07:41] Starting 'default'...
>   1>  Release|AnyCPU
>   1>  [20:07:41] Finished 'default' after 36 ms
>   ========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
> ```

So basically two ingredients:

1. Pass the mode from your calling tool (msbuild, teamcity, powershell, whatever);
2. Parse the argument in gulp (yargs, etc);

I'd assume there's a similar argument-parsing tool for Grunt...