# Gulp - start task with an argument

Tags: gulp

So I'm trying to create a gulp workflow and I'd like to implement options for some tasks, like `gulp copy-images --changed`. Now, I've created a watch task that obviously watches all image files and it should start the `copy-images` with the --changed flag.

Ideally, I want to do something like this:

```
gulp.task('copy-images', function(){
    // some code
});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch(config.images, ['copy-images --changed']);
});
```

I'm also very aware that I could do:

```
gulp.task('copy-images', function(){
    // some code
});

gulp.task('copy-images-changed', function(){
    // some code
});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch(config.images, ['copy-images']);
});
```

but this means duplicate code.
Anyone with a solution or maybe some advice?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gulp does not provide a built-in way of specifying options for tasks. You have to use an external options parser module like [`yargs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23023650/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-flag-to-gulp-to-have-it-run-tasks-in-different-ways) for more on that topic.

This also means that passing something like `['copy-images --changed']` to `gulp.watch()` will not work. The entire string will just be interpreted as a task name.

The best approach for you would be to factor out the code of your task into a function and then call this function from both your task and your watch:

```
var argv = require('yargs').argv;

function copyImages(opts) {
  if (opts.changed) {
    // some code
  } else {
    // some other code
  }
}

gulp.task('copy-images', function() {
  copyImages(argv);
});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch(config.images, function() {
      copyImages({changed:true});
    });
});
```

The above should cover all of your bases:

- `gulp copy-images` will execute `//some other code`.
- `gulp copy-images --changed` will execute `//some code`.
- `gulp watch` will execute `//some code` any time a watched file is  changed.

Comment: Okay, I was hoping there was some other solution, but thank you anyway for the clarifying answer. ;-)