# Set a variable while buiding SASS with gulp?

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I use the following in `gulp` to build a CSS file from a SASS (*.scss) file :

```
var gulp        = require('gulp')
  , sass        = require('gulp-sass');

var colortheme = 'blue';

gulp.task('build_css', function() {
  return gulp.src(['resources/assets/sass/app/' + colortheme + '.scss'])
             .pipe(sass())
             .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css/'));
} );
```

As you can see I use a different .scss file for each colortheme.

I would like to use only one .scss file but be able to pass the colortheme somehow as a parameter, so this can be used as a variable inside the .scss file.

Is this possible?

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to build all your themes, as gulp is used primarly in development? Do you care that much? Otherwise, does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23023650/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-flag-to-gulp-to-have-it-run-tasks-in-different-ways

Comment: Well, I used a simplified example. In reality I set *multiple* variables, which would result in very many different combinations, while only a few will be used  (but I don't *exactly* know which ones, this depends on the building options that were set). So having a dynamic solution seems much better to me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Considering that it's SCSS you can simply plop the variable definitions at the beginning of the file using [`gulp-header`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-header):

**resources/assets/sass/app/theme.scss**

```
.foo {
  color: $themeColor;
  font-family:$themeFont;
}
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var header = require('gulp-header');

var colortheme = 'blue';
var font = 'sans-serif';

gulp.task('build_css', function() {
  return gulp.src(['resources/assets/sass/app/theme.scss'])
   .pipe(header('$themeColor: ' + colortheme + ';\n' +
                '$themeFont: ' + font + ';\n'))
   .pipe(sass())
   .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css/'));
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems exactly what I need.

Comment: Thanks so much, It really helped me to resolve multi team in css