# Including certain modules in angularJS application builds

Tags: angularjs, build, gulp

I have feature modules in my angular application and am looking for a way to create builds that only include certain features.

For example:

```
/app
|
|--/components
|
|--/core
|
|--/dataservices
|
|--/features
   |
   |--/customers
   |
   |--/orders
```

So say I wanted to produce a build that only included the orders module, are there any tools out there that can help in achieving this?

I am using gulp, and wondered about being able to configure a gulp task that took in some arguments where you specify what modules to include and then use file globbing patterns or similar to target certain folders/files in the build.

Can anyone offer any suggestions\approaches?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to pass a flag to Gulp to have it run tasks in different ways?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23023650/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-flag-to-gulp-to-have-it-run-tasks-in-different-ways)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, let's say you wanted a gulp task that globs all js in your orders folder and sub folders. A gulp task could looks like the following

```
// Gulp Orders Task
gulp.task('orders', function() {
return gulp.src('features/orders/**/**.js')
  .pipe(concat('orders.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('app/build/js'))
  .pipe(browserSync.reload({
      stream: true
  }));
});
```

What this task does is globs all js, concatenates your js into one orders.js file into a new folder called build. It's also smart to use browserync to reload the page during development when js files change.

Your orders specific js would end up being `app/build/js/orders.js`.

The variables you would need are

```
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
```