# gulp - command-line to run a task on a specific file

Tags: node.js, command-line, terminal, gulp

I have a task `scripts` that do all that normal stuff with scripts on `watch`:

```
var folderScripts = "assets/scripts";

gulp.task('scripts', function(){
        gulp.src([
                folderScripts+'/**/*.js',
                '!'+folderScripts+'/**/_*.js',
                '!'+folderScripts+'/**/*.min.js'
            ])

            // uglify, rename, etc etc... 
            .pipe(gulp.dest( function(file) { return file.base; } ));
});
```

Sometimes, I may need to run that task `scripts` only for a specific file outside that folder, ex: `assets/plugins/flexsider/flexslider.js` I'm wondering if it would be possible to do something like this on terminal:

```
gulp scripts assets/plugins/flexsider/flexslider.js
```

and then the task scripts would replace `gulp.src()` content for a dynamic content, this case `assets/plugins/flexsider/flexslider.js`, and would be like this:

```
var folderScripts = "assets/scripts";

gulp.task('scripts', function(){
        gulp.src('assets/plugins/flexsider/flexslider.js') //this would be the "flag" I passed on terminal line
            // uglify, rename, etc etc... 
            .pipe(gulp.dest( function(file) { return file.base; } ));
});
```

I searched for gulp-exec and similares but I think it is not what i'm looking for.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to pass a flag to Gulp to have it run tasks in different ways?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23023650/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-flag-to-gulp-to-have-it-run-tasks-in-different-ways)

Comment: oww sorry i really tried to find something on stackoverflow. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Install [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs)**

```
npm install yargs --save-dev
```

**Your task:**

```
gulp.task('scripts', function(){

    // require yargs
    var args = require('yargs').argv;

    var arraySources = [
        folderScripts+'/**/*.js',
        '!'+folderScripts+'/**/_*.js',
        '!'+folderScripts+'/**/*.min.js'];

    // check for an argument called file (or whatever you want)
    // and set the source to the file if the argument exists. Otherwise set it to the array
    var source = args.file? args.file : arraySources;

    gulp.src(source)

        // uglify, rename, etc etc... 
        .pipe(gulp.dest( function(file) { return file.base; } ));
});
```

**Call your task from the prompt:**

```
gulp scripts --file=assets/plugins/flexsider/flexslider.js
```

which will run scripts on that file only.

**or**

```
gulp scripts
```

which will run scripts as before