# Assigning gulp variables via command line

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

How do I assign a value to a variable using the command line when using a gulp task.

```
gulp.task('task-name',function(value){
   var anotherValue = value;
});
```

Something like this, so when I run `gulp task-name value` I can access `value`.

I have tried using gulp-param, but that prevents some of my tasks from running.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to pass a flag to Gulp to have it run tasks in different ways?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23023650/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-flag-to-gulp-to-have-it-run-tasks-in-different-ways)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass values into a gulp task via the command line. The easiest way to do this is to use an args module like [yargs](http://yargs.js.org/).

```
var args = require('yargs').argv;

// this isn't strictly necessary but it's good to set default values
var target = args.target || 'default';

gulp.task('something', function() {
    gulp.src('*.html')
        // let's use our variable here
        .pipe(dest(target));
});
```

Then call this from the command line:

```
gulp something --target blah
```

Where `blah` will be the value of `target` inside the gulp task.

Answer (score 0):

easiest solution would be to set the env vars before calling the gulp and using them via process.env.MYVAR.

For example:

```
MY_VAR=12345
gulp
```

And in the gulp task:

```
gulp.task('task-name', function () {
  var anotherValue = process.env.MY_VAR;
}
```